# how to use sql query result in html table

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

I am trying to create a html table showing results from php sql query. it is a result page of students php code is as under

```
$r1=$_GET["r"];
$con=mysqli_connect(localhost,chumspai_tlss,Tls121,chumspai_tlsResult);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM nursery_blue_ WHERE sr_='$r1'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
```

html code is

```
<pre>
<form name="frmResult" id="frmResult" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmpty();">
  <table width="80%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td class="heading noborder">Enter Your Roll Number:</td>
      <td class="noborder"><input type="text" id="r" name="r" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <!--
      <td class="heading noborder">Enter Your Name:</td>
      <td class="noborder"><input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="heading noborder">Search by</td>
      <td class="noborder"><input type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="rno" checked="checked" />
        Roll No
        <input type="radio" id="option" name="option" value="name" />
        Name </td>
    </tr>
    -->
    <tr>
      <td class="noborder">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="noborder"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!--<tr>
        <td colspan="2"> <embed src="images/wait.swf"></embed></td>
    </tr>   -->
  </table>
</form>

                    <div style="border:1px solid #000000;">
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="heading grey" width="30%">RNO</td>
                        <td><?php
                        Print $row['sr_'];
                        ?>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="heading grey">NAME</td>
                        <td class="shade"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="heading grey">FATHER</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                        <td class="heading grey">regno</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                      <tr class="grey">
                        <td rowspan="2" class="heading">Sr.no </td>
                        <td rowspan="2" class="heading">Name of subject </td>
                        <td rowspan="2" class="heading">Maximum Marks</td>
                        <td colspan="7" class="heading">detail of marks Obtained</td>
                      <tr class="grey">
                        <td class="heading">PART ONE</td>

                        <td class="heading">Total</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Urdu</td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="shade">
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>English</td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>Islamyat</td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="shade">
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td>pakstudies</td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>

                      <tr class="shade">
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="shade">
                        <td>8</td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                        <tr class="shade">
                        <td>9</td>
                        <td></td>

                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>0</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="grey">
                        <td colspan="2" class="heading">TOTAL</td>
                        <td class="heading">1100</td>
                        <td colspan="4" class="heading"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr class="grey">
                        <td colspan="3" class="heading">NOTIFICATION</td>
                        <td class="heading"></td>
                        <td class="heading"></td>
                        <td colspan="2" class="heading"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7">(i) This provisional result intimation is issued as a notice only. Errors and omissions are excepted.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</pre>
```

please help me how to embed this php query with this html table and html form also.

Comment: think you missed some of your code... what's in `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`...?

Answer (score 2):

you are not so far.

The variable $row is an array containing your data. Try this to see it's structure in your while call:

```
print_r($row);
```

Using this command you will see the name of each item of your array. Note it somewhere. Then you can do something like this:

```
...<td><?php echo $row['desired_column_name']; ?></td>...
```

If you receive data from your mysql query, this should do the trick.

Hope it helps,
Paul

Answer (score -1):

Try This :

```
       $result = mysql_query("select * from emp");
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo "<tr>";               
            echo "<td id=SrNo$cnt >".$row['eno']."</td>";               
            echo "<td id=ItemId$cnt >".$row['eId']."</td>";               
            echo "<td>". "<button name='Update' id='update' onclick='show(".$cnt.")'>UPDATE</button>"."</td>";
            echo "<td>". "<button name='Report' id='show' onclick='Report(".$row['SrNo'].")'>REPORT</button>"."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<div id=show$cnt>";
            echo "</div>";
            $cnt++;
 }
```